# How do I solve the Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hystrix, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to write a service that will bind to another service through the eureka server and I want to use FeignClient + Hystrix, I can't implement the GET controller, I get this Exception:

```
 java.base@11/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:234)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2123)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1182)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:899)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1054)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1114)
 java.base@11/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
 java.base@11/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-10-29 14:15:14.413  INFO 5036 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-10-29 14:15:14.429 ERROR 5036 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'parserFileController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'parserServiceFeignClient'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'by.iba.hystrix.service.ParserServiceFeignClient': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity by.iba.hystrix.service.ParserServiceFeignClient.getCars(by.iba.hystrix.filter.CarFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
Warnings:
- 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1425) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:402) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at by.iba.hystrix.HystrixApplication.main(HystrixApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'by.iba.hystrix.service.ParserServiceFeignClient': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity by.iba.hystrix.service.ParserServiceFeignClient.getCars(by.iba.hystrix.filter.CarFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
Warnings:
- 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:529) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method has too many Body parameters: public abstract org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity by.iba.hystrix.service.ParserServiceFeignClient.getCars(by.iba.hystrix.filter.CarFilter,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
Warnings:
- 
    at feign.Util.checkState(Util.java:129) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:127) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringMvcContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(SpringMvcContract.java:207) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at feign.Contract$BaseContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(Contract.java:62) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixDelegatingContract.parseAndValidateMetadata(HystrixDelegatingContract.java:47) ~[feign-hystrix-10.12.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$ParseHandlersByName.apply(ReflectiveFeign.java:151) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign.newInstance(ReflectiveFeign.java:49) ~[feign-core-10.12.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixFeign$Builder.target(HystrixFeign.java:63) ~[feign-hystrix-10.12.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.HystrixTargeter.targetWithFallback(HystrixTargeter.java:74) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.HystrixTargeter.target(HystrixTargeter.java:49) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getTarget(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:416) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientFactoryBean.getObject(FeignClientFactoryBean.java:361) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClientsRegistrar.lambda$registerFeignClient$0(FeignClientsRegistrar.java:246) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.2.9.RELEASE.jar:2.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.obtainFromSupplier(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1235) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is what my controller looks like in the main service:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarController {

    private final CarService carService;

    @Autowired
    public CarController(CarService carService) {
        this.carService = carService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(CarFilter carFilter, Pageable page) {
        Page<CarDto> cars = carService.getCars(page, carFilter);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(cars, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

This is what my controller looks like in the service where I am trying to implement FeignClient:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class ParserFileController {

    @Autowired
    private ParserServiceFeignClient parserServiceFeignClient;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(CarFilter carFilter, Pageable page) {

        return parserServiceFeignClient.getCars(carFilter, page);
    }
```

This is the interface where I made FeignClient

```
@FeignClient(
        name = "PARSER-FILE-SERVICE",
        url = "http://localhost:8080/cars",
        fallback = ParserServiceFallback.class
)
public interface ParserServiceFeignClient {

    @GetMapping()
    ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(CarFilter carFilter, Pageable page);
```

And this is the Fallback class FeignClient:

```
@Component
public class ParserServiceFallback implements ParserServiceFeignClient {

    
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(CarFilter carFilter, Pageable page) {
        System.out.println("In fallback method");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new RestPageImpl<>(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

CarFilter:

```
public class CarFilter {

    private String mark;

    private Integer year;

    private String color;

    private String country;

    public CarFilter() {
    }

// getters and setters
```

Please help, I have been tormented by this task for a long time. I tried to do it via POST, but this is not suitable for obtaining a resource with RESTapi

Comment: You are using he wrong annotation on your feign interface. You should use feign \@RequestLine or Jax-rs \@GET \@PATH

Answer (score 0):

GET requests usually don't hava a body, so you have to pass params e.g. as query params.

Try using request param annotation:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(@RequestParam("car-filter") CarFilter carFilter, @RequestParam("page") Pageable page)
```

Comment: Forgive me, I didn’t specify but `CarFilter` and `Pageable`  are a collection of `@ReuestParam` of type `@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<CarDto>> getCars(@RequestParam ("markCar") String markCar, @RequestParam ("size") String size, @RequestParam ("offset") String offset ....) `Is there the ability to not break my CarFilter and Pageable wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

GET requests don't have a body, try using other mapping methods like the post. nad try to receive objects in a more specific way with some annotation like @RequestParam, or @RequestBody.

```
@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<> getCars(@RequestBody CarFilter car, ....){}
```